# ng-repeat: Dynamically generate anchor tag and corresponding HTML page for object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currenty, I'm repeating a hundreds of items in an array like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderby:-Date">
   <h3>{{post.Title}}</h3>
   <h4>{{post.Company}}</h4>
   <p>{{post.Description}}</p>
</div>
```

Which gets it's data from an object like this:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        "ID" : "1",
        "Title" : "A"
        "Company" : "Company A",
        "Date" : "2016-06-22",
        "Description" : "..."
   },{
        "ID" : "2",
        "Title" : "B"
        "Company" : "Company B",
        "Date" : "2016-06-23",
        "Description" : "..."
    },{
        "ID" : "3",
        "Title" : "C"
        "Company" : "Company C",
        "Date" : "2016-06-21",
        "Description" : "..."
    }
]
```

What I'd like to do is generate a unique link for each of the above as in `.../items/1.html` / `.../items/2.html` based on their ID and generate an html structure on that page that has the same structure as that of the `ng-repeat` div, but obviously without repeating.

Is this possible in javascript / angularJS or do I need to look into creating database entries with mySQL for each of these ID's?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but as far as i know you cannot create html files using angularjs but if you want to show html pages that have same html template you can use it using states.

```
.state('post',{
  url : '/post',
  abstract : true,
  templateUrl : 'some.html'
})
.state('post.id',{
 url : '/{id}',
 templateUrl : 'someHtml.html',
 controller : 'PostController'
});
```

in controller you can get the id's as

```
app.controller('PostController',function($scope,$stateParams){
  $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
});
```

you can call the posts, as

```
<a href="/post/{{item.id}}">View Post</a>
```

This will go to state `/post/1` and so on depending on the ids from the json. Using the controller you can display your html of that particular post without needing to create physical html pages.